# How to make an (moving) ellipse clickable? Processing

Tags: processing, ellipse, clickable

So I started learning processing since a week ago and I'm trying to get a moving ellipse clickable. I followed the processing API, but I can't figure it out. I removed all the code relating to the clickable ellipse because it was a mess.

In the section where I declare all my vars you can see me using:

```java
int breedte = 600;
int hoogte = 600;
```

These are suppose to be:

```java
int breedte = width;
int hoogte = height;
```

But for some reason the width and height don't output the width and height declared in:

```java
size(600,600)
```

**So what I'm asking is:**

1. **How can I make the (moving) ellipse clickable?**
2. **Why I can't use width and height on 'int hoogte' and 'int breedte'?**

Thanks in advace.

**Main file:**

```java
int x = 0;
int leftSide = 0;
int rightSide = width;
int bottomSide = height;

int totalHits = 0;
int totalMiss = 0;

boolean start = false;

int circelSize = 100;
int circelRings = 24;
int circelSpeed = 1;
int circelPositionY = 0;

int breedte = 600;
int hoogte = 600;

String[] buttonText = {"Start","Stop"};
String buttonTextActive = buttonText[0];
int[] buttonColor = {0,90};
int buttonColorActive = buttonColor[0];
int buttonHighlight = 50;
int buttonSize = 80;  
int buttonY = breedte - (buttonSize /2);
int buttonX = hoogte / 2 - 40;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
}

void draw() {
  if (start) {
    circelPositionY = circelPositionY + circelSpeed;
    drawCircel(circelPositionY);
    if (circelPositionY == (width + circelSize)) {
      circelPositionY = 0;
    }
  }
  drawButton();
}
```

**Events file:**

```java
void mousePressed() {
  // Start or Stop button
  if(mouseX > buttonX & mouseX < buttonX  + buttonSize & mouseY > buttonY & mouseY < buttonY + (buttonSize / 2)){
    if(start) {
      start = false;
      buttonColorActive = buttonColor[0];
      buttonTextActive = buttonText[0];
      println("Game stoped");
    } else {
      start = true;
      buttonColorActive = buttonColor[1];
      buttonTextActive = buttonText[1];
      println("Game started");
    }
  }
//HERE SHOULD GO THE CLICKABLE ELLPISE
}
```

**Functions file:**

```java
void drawCircel(int circelPositionY) {
  background(204);
  for (int i = 0; i < circelRings; i = i+1) {
    int even = i % 2;
    if (even == 0) {
      fill(255,0,0);
      ellipse(-(circelSize / 2) + circelPositionY, height / 2 - (circelSize / 2), circelSize - (i * (circelSize / circelRings)), circelSize - (i * (circelSize / circelRings)));
    } else {
      fill(255);
      ellipse(-(circelSize / 2) + circelPositionY, height / 2 - (circelSize / 2), circelSize - (i * (circelSize / circelRings)), circelSize - (i * (circelSize / circelRings)));
    }
  }
}

void drawButton() {
  fill(buttonColorActive);
  rect(buttonX,buttonY, buttonSize, buttonSize / 2);
  fill(255);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  text(buttonTextActive, buttonX + (buttonSize / 2),buttonY + (buttonSize / 4));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of a bunch of disconnected snippets or your whole project. Also please only ask one question per post.

To make your circle clickable, you're going to have to write code that checks whether the circle is being clicked. That's actually two separate checks. First you have to detect when the mouse is pressed. One way to do that is by defining a `mousePressed()` function:

```
void mousePressed(){
  // mouse is pressed
}
```

Then you have to check whether the mouse is currently inside the circle. You can use the `dist()` function for that: if the distance between the mouse and the center of the circle is less than the radius of the circle, then the mouse is inside the circle. That might look like this:

```
void mousePressed(){
  if(dist(mouseX, mouseY, circleX, circleY) < circleRadius){
    // mouse is pressed inside the circle
  }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on collision detection in Processing, including point-circle collision, available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection).

As for why you can't use `width` and `height` at the top of your sketch, that's because code at the top of your sketch is executed before the `setup()` function fires, and the `width` and `height` variables aren't set until after you call `size()` from the `setup()` function. So you have to move that code to **after** you call `size()`.

If you have follow-up questions, please post an updated [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in a new question post, and we'll go from there. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Kevin, today you are my hero. Your answer couldn't be more clear! The self-promotion is also exactly what I was looking for to add to my project, no shame on you ;). I've read the MCVE and my next post will be better.

Thanks my friend

Answer (score 1):

Processing does not provide an api for hit detection, so you need to implement this by yourself, which I think is a great learning exercise. You can explore the mathematics of an ellipse [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordgeneralellipse.html).

But the general approach is to use a function like the one below to check that the point you clicked on was indeed inside the ellipse you provided.

```
boolean InsideEllipse(
    float x, float y, 
    float xc, float yc, 
    float width, float height
) { 

    // First half the width and height to get the ellipse parameters
    float a = width / 2;
    float b = height / 2;

    // Now calculate the deltas:
    float xd = x - xc;
    float yd = y - yd;

    // Now the equation of an ellipse is given by 
    //      x^2 / a ^ 2 + y^2 / b ^ 2 = 1
    // So if we are inside the ellipse, we would expect the left hand
    // side of this expression to be less than one
    boolean inside = xd * xd / (a * a) + yd * yd / (b * b) <= 1.0
    return inside
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer verry much but I don't know how to apply this code to the code I've already written. Im getting an errow aswell on the last 2 rules.

Comment: Last two lines are missing `;`

Comment: Oh thanks yep, the last two lines are missing a semicolon. Sorry about the late reply. But this code is supposed to work with ellipses that are not necessarily circles :) If you combine what I have to Kevin Workman's response, you should be able to get this working for non circles